# Linking.openUrl to open Add New Contact Page directly in React Native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I want to open **Add New Contact** page directly of my phone's app using **Linking.openUrl** in React Native. I Googled it but not found any solution. If someone know how to do this please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open new Contacts Page directly from Linking.openUrl but you can achieve this by installing a library called as `react-native-contacts`

Official Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts

Eg:

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => {
           Contacts.openContactForm()
        }}
      >
      <Text>Create Contact</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```